# Python: Multiple return values assigned to each function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, calling-convention

```
def function_1():
  return (5)
  return (6)
  return(7)

result_1 = function_1() 
print(result_1)
```

Why is is that when I print the call of function_1(), only the first value, 5, is printed?

Comment: You haven't described your expected behaviour - what do you expect as output?

Comment: this post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return multiple values as a tuple.

```
def function_1():
  return 5, 6, 7

result_1 = function_1() 
print(result_1)

a, b, c = function_1()
print(a, b, c)
```

This outputs:

```
(5, 6, 7)
5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're returning value 5 by this `return (5)` line then `funtion_1` returns the value and terminates the function. That's why subsequent lines are not getting executed. If you want to return multiple values from a function then you can return them as a `tuple`,`list` etc. Like:

```
def function_1():
  return(5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is is that when I print the call of function_1(), only the first
>   value, 5, is printed?

Value "5" is getting printed because when you will call `function_1` then `function_1` will always return "5" and it wont execute next lines in that function. That's the reason you are always getting same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` instead, making a generator. `return` stops the function execution. The code will be like:

```
def function_1():
    yield (5)
    yield (6)
    yield (7)

for result in function_1():
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You function will terminate on the first successful `return` statement, which in this case is `5`. As others have suggested, you could wrap these values in a `tuple` or a `list`. You could also return a dictionary containing these multiple values:

```
def function_1():
    return {'first': 5, 'second': 6, 'third': 7}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
>>> result_1 = function_1()
>>> result_1
{'first': 5, 'second': 6, 'third': 7}
>>> result_1['first']
5
>>> result_1['second']
6
>>> result_1['third']
7
```